# How to create and recreate view programmatically in Android

Tags: java, android

```
 private void generateView() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            mview = new View(getActivity());
            mview.setBackgroundResource(R.color.grayColor);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    10, 40);
            layoutParams.setMargins(5, 0, 5, 0);
            mview.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            lnLinearlayout.addView(mview);
            changeProgress();
        }
    }


    public void changeProgress()

    {

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                    // Update the progress status

                    for (int i = 0; i < lnLinearlayout.getChildCount() - 1; i++) {
                        final int finalI = i;
                        progressStatus = i;
                        // Try to sleep the thread for 20 milliseconds
                        try {

                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        // Update the progress bar
                        handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                lnLinearlayout.getChildCount();
                                     lnLinearlayout.getChildAt(finalI).setBackgroundResource(R.color.blackcolor);


                            }

                        });

                    }
                }

        }).start(); // Start the operation
    }
```

This is my code I am able to create first 5 views and changing their color  from gray to black. I am trying to recreate same view and same process when it reaches to 5th position view and same process should happen till stop thread can anyone please suggest me how to do this?

Comment: You need to remove all the view added and add them again

Comment: where we have to write this thing inside  thread  or where can u please tell me @surya we have to apply some condition

Comment: @Adevelopment: `same process should happen till stop thread` please share crash logs

Comment: how yaar we need some apply condition na coz if we ll have apply condition  how i will recreate view and start again from gray to black continuslly

Comment: You need to do all View operation on UIThread , Read about UiThread on Android site